# Regular expression for printable ASCII, but not allowing string that all characters are space

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression that accept only printable ASCII set as follows.

```
([!-~]|[ ])*
```

But i want to reject the string that have everything as space like

```
"        "
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: `\\S+` will match everything that isn't white-space.

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch,  want to match if the string contains white space, only want to reject if all the characters are white space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
"^(?=[ \\t]*\\S)([!-~]|[ ])*"
```

`(?=[ \\t]*\\S)` asserts that there must be atleast one non-space character would present on that particular line.

**OR**

```
string.matches("(?=\\s*\\S)([!-~]|[ ])*");
```

Note that the `\\s` matches line breaks also.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rR5zI0/3)

```
String s[] = {"foo bar", "    ","bar"};
for(String i:s)
{
    System.out.println(i.matches("(?=[ \\t]*\\S)([!-~]|[ ])*"));
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash Raj. Working fine

Comment: Since i have to use the regular expression in XSD, look ahead are not supported by XSD. I have comeup with the following regular expression. ([ ]*([!-~])[ ]*)+     This seems like working

Answer (score 1):

If empty strings `""` should also not pass your regex test, then simply `String#Trim()` your input before the match. Change your regex quantifier from `*` to `+` i.e. at least one character is required.

```
([!-~]|[ ])+
```

Then empty strings or strings with only spaces will fail to match your regex.

Comment: The line would get trimmed to `""` and fail to match the regex.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but i am using this regexp in XSD. So any processing of string is not possible i think

Answer (score 0):

Since i have to use the regular expression in XSD, the following regular expression cannot be used

```
^(?=[ \\t]*\\S)([!-~]|[ ])*
```

But i have used the following expression, that seems like working for me. A simple expression without any look ahead

```
([ ]*([!-~])[ ]*)+
```